# How to execute code after returning view in Yii2

Tags: events, callback, yii, yii2

Normally when you call a page in Yii2, pretty much the last thing that happens is that the view is rendered to the end user's screen.  I need to run code after this that might take a second or two and I don't want to have the user wait.

My first thought was to set a global event that gets called after the response is set so I added this to a method:

```
if (condition is met) {
    Yii::$app->on(yii\web\Response::EVENT_AFTER_SEND, function ($event) {
        // do stuff
    });
}
```

But this doesn't seem to ever get called.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or have a better idea on how to solve this problem?  I just need to run code after the view is rendered.  I don't really care how it happens.

Comment: If it's a separate part of code then send the ajax request after the view is rendered.

Comment: It needs to be done without AJAX

Comment: [Event After Render is your option then](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-view#EVENT_AFTER_RENDER-detail)